# How to change the scrollbar style for ngx-datatable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, angular, ngx-datatable

I am using the ngx datatable in my angular app, I am unable to change the scrollbar style for this table.

```
.ngx-datatable::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    border-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

Not worked...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ngx-datatable::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    border-radius: 8px !important;
}
```